# Internal Competition vs Collaboration

Tags: strategy

Suppose you are a senior executive designing an organization that owns multiple brands in an industry. You can either structure the business unit to have each brand compete or collaborate.

How do you decide which philosophy to adopt? Does it depend on the size of the organization? The degree of separation between the brands? The profitability of the industry?

Comment: Maybe better suited to workplace.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Hi user, welcome to PMSE! Try searching [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/search) as someone may have asked this there. PMSE is really for questions about the field of product management, and this is more of a product management question that *may* fit better on OnStartups. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above. It depends solely on the people and culture of the organization.

(also: collaboration is almost always a better choice. Competitors can collaborate, but collaborators have a hard time thriving in a highly competitive environment).